# Get the height of an element and show/hide More... button depending on the element's height

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm new to React and NextJs. I want to get the height of an element and depending on its height, to show or not to show the `More...` button.

What I've tried is this:

```
import {useRef, useState} from "react";

const MyText = (props) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(null)
  const setContent = (e) => {
    setMyState(e)
  }

  const myRef = useRef(null)
  const needsMoreButton = () => {
    console.log(myRef) // It's null
    console.log(myState) // It's null too!
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <p ref={myRef} onLoad={setContent} className="max-h-20 overflow-hidden">If it has multiple lines of text, to show "More..." and if it has only one line of text, not to show "More..."</p>
      {
        needsMoreButton() && <button>More...</button>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyText
```

So it seems the `onLoad` is not triggered and `myRef` is not filled with the p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **onLoad** event is not supported by the p element, so it won't work as you expect. Instead, you can use the **useEffect** hook to calculate the height of the element after it has been rendered.

```
import {useRef, useState, useEffect} from "react";

const MyText = (props) => {
 const [needsMoreButton, setNeedsMoreButton] = useState(false)
 const myRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
 const height = myRef.current.clientHeight
 setNeedsMoreButton(height > 20) // or any other threshold you choose
},   [])

return (
  <div>
    <p ref={myRef} className="max-h-20 overflow-hidden">If it has multiple 
  lines of text, to show "More..." and if it has only one line of text, not 
  to show "More..."</p>
   {
     needsMoreButton && <button>More...</button>
   }
  </div>
   )
 }

export default MyText
```